# What flooring can be used for a gypcrete subfloor?

Tags: concrete, flooring, staining, epoxy

My question is about what to do after the malfunctioning washing machine flooded the basement. We tried an acid stain on the 'concrete' floor. It failed. We followed with two coats of epoxy pain. It failed. A 'concrete' expert examined the floor and found it was gypcrete. Also there are cracks in the subfloor and a coring showed no moisture barrier or gravel base. The discarded floorings showed no sign of moisture or mold.

Research shows gypcrete lacks the chemicals for an acid stain reaction so we understand the failure (maybe). But, what are floor options now?

Answer (score 1):

You have two major problems: 1) Gypcrete is designed to be installed over a wood support, not on gravel or soil, and 2) Gypcrete is not designed to be a final finish surface. That is to say, it’s not made to be walked on...you need a finish flooring, like carpet, sheet vinyl, wood, etc.

Call your insurance company and tell them about your washing machine problem and tell them the flooring (Gypcrete) needs to be removed. Remove it and then install a concrete slab.